# i printed hello world at fisrt but after changing it its showing the printing hello world again and again in the terminal

Tags: c, printf

[image]

I wrote a program to print hello world at first.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf("age is age");
   
    return 0;

}
```

and when I open in a terminal
it keeps showing hello world
as I wrote it previously.

Comment: Did you recompile it?

Comment: Be sure to save the file before compiling as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Never provide pictures of code or text. Instead copy/paste your code into your question and include `\`\`\`lang` (where lang is `c`, `c++`, `bash`, `awk`, etc..) on the line above the code and `\`\`\`` (those are backticks) on the line below it to format as code with syntax highlight. For plain text use `\`\`\`none` on the line above, same `\`\`\`` on the line below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *white dot* after the file name indicates you haven't saved the changes in the file. In order to compile the changes, You have to save the file before compiling it otherwise it will recompile the last saved file.

**This will definitely work**

1. save the file. [`ctrl + S`]
2. recompile the file.
3. run the `.exe` file

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation that makes sense to me as to why this is happening is that you did not *save* the file before recompiling, so you're recompiling the same source and thus getting the same result when running a.exe.